# MySQL query replying OK

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a sql database and I need to find out a list of products IDs, so far we have filtred some data and now we are trying to filter some producer names,  [Here's a example about what producers has inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxcfh.png)

We tried to obtain all the producers with non-human names by using the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM producers WHERE metadata REGEXP'{"name":  "[0-9]';
```

but the result is always "OK" [Feedback from MySQL saying OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUTh.png)

I was hoping to filter any name with numbers instead of human names.

Comment: How did you try that? Usually, MySQL won't reply "Ok"

Comment: Can you give a example dataset(sql)

Comment: Occasionally it may happen that errors are not displayed correctly and simply come up 'OK' try this query and see what comes up
-->
show errors;

Comment: Is 'metadata' column is json format

Comment: Having OK returned is well behaved but not expected. I'm questioning about your regex. I would rather go to something like SELECT * FROM producers WHERE metadata REGEXP '^{"name": .{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12}".*';

Comment: I see 2 space chars between `:` and `"`. Of course you cannot find matched rows...

Comment: *We tried to obtain all the producers with non-human names* No. You try to find the rows where the name contains a digit. I see 2 types of the value - human names and GUIDs. Formally GUID may contain only letters and not digits, so your criteria is not correct. If there is no 3rd name pattern then I'd recommend you to test the name attribute for it does not match the  GUID pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The query replies "Ok", perhaps because there is no matching row.

you can try the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM producers WHERE metadata REGEXP '{"name": "[a-z0-9].*';
```

Comment: This will match both real names and GUID's

Comment: @Civette Real name begins with a capital letter

Comment: According screenshot, yes but not sure this can be taken as granted..... I'd rather chase for GUID pattern even if I must admit that we don't have much info on what can be found in the field